System.Invalid The instance of entity type 'LecAttendanceEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the keyvalue is already being tracked
[HttpPost("PostLecAttendance")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostLecAttendance([FromBody] LectureAttendanceRequestDto request)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }

   var lectureDetails = await _attendanceRepository.GetLectureDetailsEntity(request.LectureId);

   if (lectureDetails.AttendanceMarked.HasValue && lectureDetails.AttendanceMarked.Value != true)
   {
       lectureDetails.AttendanceMarked = true;
   }

   var currentAttendance = await _attendanceRepository
       .GetLectureAttendanceEntity(request.LectureId);

   var updates = new List<LecAttendanceEntity>();
   var inserts = new List<LecAttendanceEntity>();

   foreach (var attendance in request.Attendances)
   {
       var admission = currentAttendance
         .SingleOrDefault(s => s.AdmissionId == attendance.AdmissionId);

       if (admission != null)
       {
           admission.IsPresent = attendance.IsPresent;
           updates.Add(admission);
       }
       else
       {
           var entity = Mapper.Map<LecAttendanceEntity>(attendance);
           inserts.Add(entity);
       }
   }

   var result = await _attendanceRepository.SaveAttendanceChanges(lectureDetails,
       updates, inserts);
   return Ok(request);
}

This is my Main Controller method:
   public async Task<List<LecAttendanceEntity>> GetLectureAttendanceEntity(Guid id)
       {       
           var lectureAttendance = await _dbContext.LecAttendances.AsNoTracking()
           .Where(s => s.LectureDetailsId == id)
           .ToListAsync();
            return lectureAttendance;
       }

   public async Task<int> SaveAttendanceChanges(LecLectureDetailEntity entity,List<LecAttendanceEntity> updateAttendance
       ,List<LecAttendanceEntity>newAttendance)
   {
       _dbContext.LecLectureDetails.Update(entity);
      await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

       if (updateAttendance.Any())
       {
           _dbContext.LecAttendances.UpdateRange(updateAttendance);
       }
       if (newAttendance.Any())
       {
         await  _dbContext.LecAttendances.AddRangeAsync(newAttendance);
       }
      
       var status= await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       return status;
   }
 

   public async Task<LecLectureDetailEntity> GetLectureDetailsEntity(Guid id)
   {
       var lectureDetails = await _dbContext.LecLectureDetails.AsNoTracking()
      .Where(s => s.LectureDetailsId == id && s.IsActive == true)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
       return lectureDetails;         
   }    

And above three are my Repository methods.
  public partial class LecLectureDetailEntity
  {
      public LecLectureDetailEntity()
      {
          LecAssignedBatches = new HashSet<LecAssignedBatchEntity>();
          LecAttendances = new HashSet<LecAttendanceEntity>();
          LecTopicsAssigneds = new HashSet<LecTopicsAssignedEntity>();
      }

      public Guid LectureDetailsId { get; set; }
      public Guid? SubjectId { get; set; }
      public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
      public Guid? BranchId { get; set; }
      public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
      public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
      public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
      public string? StartTime { get; set; }
      public string? EndTime { get; set; }
      public string? Notes { get; set; }
      public bool? AttendanceMarked { get; set; }
      public Guid? AcademicYearId { get; set; }
      public string? LectureStatus { get; set; }
      public int LectureNumber { get; set; }

      public virtual EmployeeDetailEntity? Employee { get; set; }
      public virtual CourseSubjectEntity? Subject { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<LecAssignedBatchEntity> LecAssignedBatches { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<LecAttendanceEntity> LecAttendances { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<LecTopicsAssignedEntity> LecTopicsAssigneds { get; set; }
  }

Above is LecLectureDetailEntity
 public partial class LecAttendanceEntity
 {
     public Guid LecAttendanceId { get; set; }
     public Guid? AdmissionId { get; set; }
     public DateTime? AttendanceDate { get; set; }
     public Guid? LectureDetailsId { get; set; }
     public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
     public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
     public bool? IsPresent { get; set; }
     public int? UploadType { get; set; }
     public string? BiometricDeviceId { get; set; }

     public virtual AdmissionDetailEntity? Admission { get; set; }
     public virtual LecLectureDetailEntity? LectureDetails { get; set; }
 }

Above is LecAttendenceEntity
Here I am trying to update the list but while updating I am getting this above Entity Framework issue, and also I do not want that Entity.Detached solution also. Help me to find out the cause and solution which will be correct.

Which line throws the exception? Also, please show the LecLectureDetailEntity and LecAttendanceEntity classes. We must have an impression of the content of the objects entering SaveAttendanceChanges.

_dbContext.LecAttendances.UpdateRange(updateAttendance);
This is line throws exception and also i might have doubt that , it is coming from
var admission = currentAttendance
.SingleOrDefault(s => s.AdmissionId == attendance.AdmissionId);
this line.

and also I have Added the both classes into problem description

Explicit Update and UpdateRange are not needed. EF Core tracks changes automatically. Also remove AsNoTracking - you need tracking entities.

There could very well be duplicate LecLectureDetailEntitys in entity (if its LecAttendances collection is populated) and updateAttendance or newAttendance.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
